# C# Update ProgressBar based on number of tasks

Tags: c#, listview, foreach, backgroundworker

Stuck on 1 tiny little problem with my application. I have a ProgressBar which I am updating using backGroundWorker in C#, updating the progressBar isn't a problem as I just call the reportProgress method.

However lets say I have a listView box with items in it, and I want to report the progress after each item has been processed, I can get the total number of items in the listView with listView1.Items.Count(); but I can't figure out how to work that out for the reports...

Example:

If I have 7 items in my listView, each item can take a different amount of time depending on the listView file size (it's a media conversion project converting audio files) so I can't just call a thread sleep function for the progressBar. I need to know the code used to get the progressBar to update acurately, or something I can run in a loop like

foreach (ListViewItem item in ConversionQueue.Items.Count())
{ }

Any help appreciated...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure if i understand your question correctly but as far as i can tell this could be a solution to your problem:

Get the total amount of work to be done first (total file size). This is your ProgressBar's maximum. Assign each of the items the amount of work it is representing (size of this single file). When a task completes add the amount of work that has been done to the progress bars value and you're good to go.

Comment: I could do this but wouldn't I need to work out the percentages etc? Basically I simply need to write some code to figure out how much work needs to be done (example if there is 5 files to convert, it would need to add 20% after each file to the progressBar) but I can't predefine it, as the end user could be adding 5 files 1 time then 200 files on another queue, this software will be given away free by the way so thanks for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: You dont have to specify a percentage. The max. Value can be anything you want, the value of the progress bar will be put in relation to the maximum value and the "filled" percentage is calculated automatically.

Comment: Thanks Jonas, I simply had to programmatically set the max value to the listView count (total listView items) and update it by 1 after each task in the loop (i = 1; i++;). If you add an answer I will mark it as correct. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Just set the maximum value to number of items in the list view. Add one to the value of the progress bar after each item has finished. And your progress bar perfectly represents the number of items done/to go.

Answer (score 0):

set Progressbar.maximum = listview.items.count

and on **ProgressChanged** event increment it by 1